# Create volatile Excel function that is run upon format change

Tags: excel, function

I am new to creating Excel functions and I need to create a function that takes a range of cells, and calculates the sum of the value of the cells that are not strikethrough.

```
Function SUMNOTSTRIKE(rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not (cell.Font.StrikeThrough) Then
            SUMNOTSTRIKE = SUMNOTSTRIKE + cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

This function works fine, but I do not understand why the result is not refreshed automatically when striking through or removing strike through. I have to execute the function again.

I read something about `Application.Volatile`, but this only works upon value change. I need the function to be triggered upon format change.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You will have to find a proxy (e.g. write an event handler which targets the selection change event.) Or -- perhaps run your function automatically every few seconds.

Comment: Got it, thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comment. If you add

```
Application.Volatile
```

to your function definition (by convention, as the first line) and then in the worksheet's code module have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Then anytime the selection is changed, all volatile functions will be recalculated. There won't be any recalculation if you just change the strikethrough of the selected cell and keep that cell selected, but the instant you move on to a different cell, your function could be updated.

As a warning, triggering `Application.Calculate` all the time could slow down Excel. Depending on your situation, this might not be an adequate solution.

Comment: It is not working. That private function should be applied somewhere in particular, or it is automatically executed?

Comment: The function `SUMNOTSTRIKE` should be in a standard code module (one that you created by `Insert > Module` in the VBA editor) and the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub should be in the worksheet's code module that is already in the editor automatically, for the worksheet that contains the formula. I tested it and it should work as described.

Comment: THX A LOT WORKED!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of John's excellent suggestion.  Say we have data in **A1** through **A100**.

We can use the double-click event to both:

- strike-through the cell's text
- force a re-calculation

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Target.Font.Strikethrough = True
    Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
```

Double-clicking a cell of interest will both strike it and force the re-calc.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: I like this approach. It kills two birds with one stone since it is somewhat annoying to add strikethroughs through the usual user interface.